# May a single-threaded application time out trying to connect a QTcpSocket to its own QTcpServer in blocking mode?

Tags: c++, qt, networking

I need to test a feature in my library that requires usage of sequential QIODevices. I have written code like this:

```
QTcpServer server;
QVERIFY(server.listen());
quint16 port = server.serverPort();
QTcpSocket socket;
socket.connectToHost(QHostAddress(QHostAddress::LocalHost), port);
QVERIFY(socket.waitForConnected());
QVERIFY(server.waitForNewConnection(30000));
QTcpSocket *client = server.nextPendingConnection();
// send some data to socket
socket.disconnectFromHost();
QVERIFY(socket.waitForDisconnected());
QVERIFY(client->waitForReadyRead());
QByteArray received = client->readAll();
client->close();
// check the data received
```

So far it seems to work (tested in Win7x64/MSVS2012 and Ubuntu/GCC). However, I am worried about this particular part:

```
QVERIFY(socket.waitForConnected());
QVERIFY(server.waitForNewConnection(30000));
```

Can't this thing sort of dead-lock (well, actually, time-out)? As far as I know, `waitForConnected()` tries to perform a connection in non-blocking mode and then call select() or poll() or whatever to actually get the job done. Meanwhile, on the other side someone has to call `accept()` for the `waitForConnected()` call to succeed, right? In this case, this someone is the next line calling `waitForNewConnection()`. But this line is only executed after the connection is successfully established. As far as I understand it, it works because the OS accepts my connection on the TCP level nevertheless without actually waiting for the `accept()` call.

Can this behavior be relied upon or it may suddenly time out on some systems? I really don't want to go into the world of slots and signals just for this one test, as it will make it much more complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you in fact want non-sequential devices, then sockets are entirely the wrong thing to use. You want a `QBuffer`. Sockets are sequential, not random-access.

If you made a typo and do want a sequential device, then simply subclass `QBuffer` and override its `isSequential` method to return true.

Your code as written is correct. You could use `QLocalServer` and `QLocalSocket` instead, or even write a simple `QIODevice` pair yourself.

Comment: Oops, I meant sequential of course. The library (QuaZIP) works fine with non-sequential devices, the (limited) support for sequential devices is a new feature. I thought about subclassing QBuffer or even QIODevice, but decided to test it with sockets as it is a more typical use case. Thanks for the heads-up on QLocalServer - I had no idea about those.

Comment: So the code will work on all OS? Thanks to the backlog mechanism or whatever?

Comment: @SergeyTachenov There is no backlog mechanism. The acceptance of a connection is done by the TCP/IP stack, not your application. Your application (Qt code) is merely notified that a connection was accepted. There's nothing the application can (or cannot) do to affect the acceptance of a connection - short of terminating, that is.

Comment: I meant the OS backlog mechanism. Like in the `backlog` parameter that is passed to the `listen()` call. I've just looked into Qt sources, and looks like QTcpServer passes the backlog of 50, and there's a comment saying something about this being ignored on systems with SYN cookies support (obviously). What I'm worrying about is that some rare OS may ignore the backlog, not support SYN cookies, and simply wait for me to call `accept()` instead.